# Array and loop in a SQL Server trigger, how to?

Tags: sql-server, arrays, loops, triggers

I am creating a trigger on a table in a SQL Server database.

But what I am unable to do is this: I have variables `@pageid` and `@templateid` populated, and I need to read all template column id's from one table - basically get a list of them (they depend on the template id and can vary in number) so I need some way of making an array or something and go through it and add it to a table.

So...

1. how do I read all template id's (image below: from 1st table (available template fields) - `where availabletemplateid is @templateid`) into an array?
2. how do I loop through this array and add them one by one it to another table (image below: 2nd table - (public page to field mapping) with `publicpageid = @pageid` and fieldid is one by one from the previous step, and field content is "-")

[image]

So far I have

```
ALTER TRIGGER CreatePageFields
ON dbo.PublicPages
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

/* variables */
DECLARE
    @pageid bigint,
    @templateid bigint

/* insert template fields for this page */
SELECT @pageid = id, @templateid = templateid FROM inserted

/* TODO 1 get all template field id's */
/* TODO 2 insert each templatefieldid / page combination */    

/* execute */
COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: First of all: **break out** from your procedural thinking! Don't think in arrays and loops when dealing with SQL Server - **think in sets of rows!** Second: your trigger should be **as lightweight as possible** - don't do too much processing in a trigger! And third: your trigger's `Inserted` table will potentially contain **multiple rows** that have been affected by a SQL statement - your `SELECT @pageid = id, @templateid = templateid FROM inserted` will **FAIL** miserably in such a case! SQL Server triggers are called **once per statement** and NOT once per row

Comment: this will always be one row insert. always. and so far none of the answers work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need an array (table variable) or any looping (cursor).  Something like this will be much, much faster (guessing at your table and field names):

```
INSERT INTO publicpagetofieldmapping (PublicPageID, FieldID, FieldContent)
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID, '-'
FROM INSERTED t1
JOIN AvailableTemplateFields t2
ON t1.TemplateID = t2.availabletemplateid
```

Comment: Kudos to @mdoyle for both giving you the answer to your actual question and then telling you not to do it that way!  I believe this is what they were referring to.

Comment: i don't get it. insert should be into PublicPageFieldMapping table (second one in the image)

Comment: and yeah it was awesome of him :)

Comment: Gotcha - they also paid closer attention.  I've modified the query to match your tables and fields.

Comment: Right, you don't want to insert the TemplateFieldID, you want the contents of the field.  What's the inserted field that you want to store?  Joining on the AvailableTemplateFields table will accomplish what you're trying to do with the loop.

Comment: i need to insert into publicpagetofieldmapping table, the three fields: publicpageid, fieldid, and as fieldcontent '-'. but there can be more than one entry.

Comment: this doesn't work. wrong table, wrong fields, i can't make it work.

Comment: So [fieldcontent] is just '-' for now and you'll change it later?  See revised query...

Comment: yes, but the table name is wrong, filed names are wrong and i cannot get it to work. i am not at this query > 


INSERT INTO PublicPageToFieldMapping (@ pageid, id2, '-')
SELECT ID as id2, AvailableTemplateID
FROM AvailableTemplateFields
WHERE (AvailableTemplateID = @ templateid) ?< a derivative from yours, but it fails with incorect sytnax at id2 when i try to save it

Comment: also i dont get why are you still using inserted? i got what i needed from it via the SELECT @ pageid = id, @ templateid = templateid FROM inserted

Comment: as it is now (in the answer) i get violation of primary key constraint

Comment: Gotcha.  Since we're inserting multiple rows, you can't have PublicPageID be part of the primary key in publicpagetofieldmapping.  You should add a new publicpagetofieldmappingID INT as the primary key and the PublicPageID and FieldIDs will be foreign keys.

Comment: k that fixed that problem. thnx a lot. but now the issue is that it added the correct NUMBER of times, but always the first one, it did not go through them in order. so i have the same field mapped 4 times, instead of 4 fields each mapped 1 time.

Comment: k figured that one out, the query should be this > INSERT INTO publicpagetofieldmapping (PublicPageID, FieldID, FieldContent)
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID, '-'
FROM INSERTED t1
JOIN AvailableTemplateFields t2
ON t1.TemplateID = t2.availabletemplateid

Comment: thnx a lot for your patience <3 edited your answer to reflect this and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cursor:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID
FROM AvailableTemplateFields
WHERE AvailableTemplateID = @templateid;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @current_template_id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO PublicPageFieldMapping (
        PublicPageID, FieldID, FieldContent
    ) VALUES (
        @pageid, @current_template_id, '-'
    );

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @current_template_id;
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

EDIT:  Although this is the way to do it "with an array" (not that a cursor is an array, but the logic is the same as far as reading DB records into it and then stepping through it), you should also be able to accomplish this with a straight query, which would be faster.

Comment: hey i'd like a query better (this seems a rather complex way), just didn't know it was possible, or how, so please can you tell me that as well? thnx

Comment: A cursor in a trigger - that's about the **best and most reliable way** to kill any performance in your system. **DON'T DO IT** - period.

Comment: it will be rarely used, but yeah the answer was to my EXACT question. i shall try it first simply to see how it works then try and adapt the query provided by russell fox

Comment: @b0x0rz, do not consider using a cursor in a trigger, this is one of the single worst mistakes you can make in a database and it can take a production database to it's knees. This is an unacceptable solution.

Comment: @b0x0rz If you are using cursor (trigger or not) add keywords [local and fast_forward](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to declaration to save some time.

Comment: Thanks for down-voting me for answering his question, folks.

Comment: i tried, fails, something like cursor not open? i upvoted because it was the answer that i asked.

Comment: You should use the query @Russell Fox provided, not the cursor.  I provided that as it was the closest answer to your question, and is a handy thing to know about for the right situation.  If you have a question about cursors in general, it might be worthwhile to open a new question and post the code you have.